# How to clone a tr with unique tr id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am cloning a `tr` like below.

```
   $tr    = $('#dummyTr');
   var $clone = $tr.clone();
   $clone.find(':text').val('');
   var cloned = $tr.after($clone);
```

but I want clone with `tr id` like this `<tr id="clone-1">`
ihave scene lots of method but every one is assigning it to `td`but i need assign it to `tr`and i did not find any method any help

Comment: my id will be unique i will pass parm in id in short i need to be unique tr

Comment: Paradigm-shift: you don't need the ID.  (you might think you do, but you don't (in 99% of cases, maybe you have an exception, but could likely still do without the ID))

Comment: i am making pos system on click image it generate tr and i am setting background color of tr and at one time only 1 tr should have background color if a user click a old image which already generated tr then this tr should have background color

Comment: Can't even see how you would use a "unique" id for that - give it a class, eg "latest" - style that class then remove class from others eg `$(".latest").removeClass("latest"); $clone.addClass("latest")`

Comment: when user clicks i get `click = $(this).data('id')` and when i assign id i use `$clone.prop('id', 'clone-'+click);` so its everytime unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can assign the `id` after you clone an object:

```
var $clone = $('#dummyTr').clone();

$clone.prop('id', 'clone-1');
```